# Ternary operator issue in React's componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ternary

I have an issue with the ternary operator in my component. I've created a function to check if Sun's up and return boolean:

```
dayTime() {
  const time = new Date();
  const sunrise = new Date(this.state.sunrise*1000);
  const sunset = new Date(this.state.sunset*1000);
  return time > sunrise && time < sunset;
}
```

I than used ternary operator to call the function and set backgroundImage depending on boolean:

```
componentDidMount() {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + (this.dayTime()? day_img_cov : night_img_cov) + ")";
    }
```

Unfortunately, the ternary won't work properly. It picks the second image all the time. Yet when I use the ternary inside of render(), it works correctly:

```
render() {

  return (
    <div className="app" style={{backgroundImage: "url(" + (this.dayTime()? day_img : night_img) + ")"}}>
      ...
    </div>
}
```

Comment: It is much better to use it in render. To manipulate the DOM from componendDidMount is react-antipattern anyways.

Comment: `cDM` is only invoked during the initial mount, never during updates. Better move the calculation in `render`. Also, `render` will not trigger itself. Either props or state must change. So you would also need an internal timer to keep refreshing the dayTime value. And welcome to SO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown your full class so I don't know where `this.state.sunrise` and `this.state.sunset` is coming from, but I'm betting they're not set properly when you call `this.dayTime()` in `componentDidMount`.

Either initialize them properly in your constructor or make sure you update the background of body whenever they are modified.

The best way of doing it is your second, working, example since that's automatically run whenever the state changes - it also doesn't modify the DOM outside of the React tree, which is good practice.

Comment: Thank you @Raniz! I've moved my ternary operator to the component's render section.

Answer (score 0):

Use `isDaytime` as a state and manipulate the classes based on that. The `dayTime` function can even be private outside of class (if it not uses state variables).

**js**

```
import classnames from 'classnames'

class Wallpaper extends Component {
  state = {
    isDaytime: daytime();
  }

  render() {
    const { isDaytime } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className={classnames('bg', {
        bg__daytime: isDaytime 
        bg__sunset: !isDaytime
      })} />
    )
  }
}
```

**css**

```
.bg {
  ...
}

.bg__daytime {
  background-image: url(day_img.png);
}

.bg__sunset {
  background-image: url(night_img.png);
}
```